Overrides in package.json not working for Lambda deployment in Amplify Gen2
I am trying to deploy a Lambda function to register Amazon Connect contact history in DynamoDB via Appsync using Amplify Gen2.
The Lambda function is as follows:
import { Handler, ConnectContactFlowEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";
import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync';

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: "xxx",
    region: 'xxx',
    auth: {
      type: "API_KEY",
      apiKey: "xxx",
    },
    disableOffline: true,
  });

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {

  await createContactHistory(event);

  return { result: "success" };
};

async function createContactHistory(event: ConnectContactFlowEvent) {
  const contactHistory = {
    contactId: event.Details.ContactData.ContactId,
    inboundPhoneNumber: event.Details.ContactData.CustomerEndpoint.Address
  };

  return await client.mutate({
    variables: contactHistory,
    mutation: CreateContactHistory
  })
}

const CreateContactHistory = gql`
  mutation MyMutation($contactId: String!, $inboundPhoneNumber: AWSPhone!) {
    createContactHistory(
      input: { contactId: $contactId, inboundPhoneNumber: $inboundPhoneNumber }
    ) {
      contactId
      createdAt
      inboundPhoneNumber
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;



However, the deployed Lambda function's index.mjs contained over 500 lines of code I didn't write, and a error message, so it wouldn't run.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.


https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions


Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.

Following the instructions in the article, the build and npm install were successful.
Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used
Here's what my package.json looks like now.
{
  "name": "amplify-vite-react-template",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite && npx ampx sandbox",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.11.10", 
    "@aws-amplify/data-schema": "^1.5.1",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^6.2.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.5",
    "@mui/material": "^6.1.8",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.22.3",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.30",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.9.0",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.10",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.38",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "graphql": "15.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/backend": "^1.1.1",
    "@aws-amplify/backend-cli": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "aws-cdk": "^2.138.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.138.0",
    "constructs": "^10.3.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.20.2",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "tsx": "^4.7.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

I tried using 'yarn install' and 'resolutions', but the situation did not change.
